# Unity C++ DLL crash when calling handler passed from Unity to C# wrapper to Native lib

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll

I have found a C++ lib https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib and I am trying to write a C# wrapper around it to be able to use it from Unity.

To bind handlers for POST / GET routes you use;

```cpp
server->Post("my/route", [](const httplib::Request& req, httplib::Response& res) {
  // do logic here
})
```

I have created a C++ project, and wrote some of my types there which will be used as intermediary types since I don't need all the data. Then I wrote my UServer class which manages the httplib::Server class and there I have

```
void UServer::Post(const char* pattern, RequestHandler handler)
{
    m_Server->Post(pattern, [=](const httplib::Request& req, httplib::Response& res)
    {
        userver::Request* u_req = userver::request_to_urequest(req);
        userver::Response* u_res = userver::response_to_uresponse(res);

        (*handler)(u_req, u_res);

        // Free memory
        safe_delete(u_req);
        safe_delete(u_res);
    });
}
```

Next, I have created helper methods and exposed them with

```
extern "C" {

    USERVER_API UServer* UServer_New(const char* hostname, int port,
        const char* cert, const char* key)
    {
        return new UServer(hostname, port, cert, key);
    }

    USERVER_API void UServer_Delete(UServer* server)
    {
        delete server;
    }

    USERVER_API void UServer_Start(UServer* server)
    {
        server->Start();
    }

    USERVER_API void UServer_Stop(UServer* server)
    {
        server->Stop();
    }

    USERVER_API void UServer_Post(UServer* server, const char* route, RequestHandler handler)
    {
        server->Post(route, handler);
    }
}
```

Now in C#, I wrote a wrapper class for that class

```
   public sealed class Server : IDisposable
    {

        private delegate void ServerRequestHandlerNative(IntPtr reqPtr, IntPtr resPtr);
        public delegate void ServerRequestHandler(Request req, Response res);

        [DllImport("UServer", EntryPoint = "UServer_New")]
        private static extern IntPtr UServer_New(string hostname, int port, string cert, string key);

        [DllImport("UServer", EntryPoint = "UServer_Delete")]
        private static extern void UServer_Delete(IntPtr server);

        [DllImport("UServer", EntryPoint = "UServer_Start")]
        private static extern void UServer_Start(IntPtr server);

        [DllImport("UServer", EntryPoint = "UServer_Stop")]
        private static extern void UServer_Stop(IntPtr server);

        [DllImport("UServer", EntryPoint = "UServer_Post")]
        private static extern void UServer_Post(IntPtr server, string route, IntPtr handler);

        [DllImport("UServer", EntryPoint = "UServer_Get")]
        private static extern void UServer_Get(IntPtr server, string route, IntPtr handler);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[C#] Called dispose.");
            UServer_Delete(m_ServerPtr);
        }

        private IntPtr m_ServerPtr;

        public Server(string hostname, int port, string cert, string key)
        {
            m_ServerPtr = UServer_New(hostname, port, cert, key);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            UServer_Start(m_ServerPtr);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            UServer_Stop(m_ServerPtr);
        }

        public void Post(string route, ServerRequestHandler handler)
        {
            ServerRequestHandlerNative nativeHandler = delegate (IntPtr reqPtr, IntPtr resPtr)
            {
                RequestNative reqNat = Marshal.PtrToStructure<RequestNative>(reqPtr);
                ResponseNative resNat = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ResponseNative>(resPtr);

                Request req = UServerUtils.NativeRequestToRequest(reqNat);
                Response res = UServerUtils.NativeResponseToResponse(resNat);

                Console.WriteLine("[C#] GET Successfully marshaled data. Now calling handler.");

                handler(req, res);
            };

            UServer_Post(m_ServerPtr, route, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(nativeHandler));
        }
```

and finally I am using it in Unity from Start() Mono's method

```
            _serverTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string hostname = "localhost";
                int port = 6060;
                string cert = $"{Application.streamingAssetsPath}/server.crt";
                string key = $"{Application.streamingAssetsPath}/server.key";

                ImGuiLogger.Instance.Log("CertPath = " + cert);
                ImGuiLogger.Instance.Log("KeyPath = " + key);

                _server = new UServerNET.Server(hostname, port, cert, key);
                _server.Post("/THLinkAPI/ConnectionChanged", THLinkApiController.PostConnectionChangedUServer);
                _server.Post("/THLinkAPI/PushEvent", THLinkApiController.PostPushEventUServer);
                _server.Start();

                MainThreadDispatcher.Instance.Enqueue(() =>
                {
                    ImGuiLogger.Instance.Log("UServer started on " + hostname + ":" + port);
                });
            }, _tokenSrc.Token);
```

The problem is, only the last bound Post handler works, if I try to send request that triggers any of the before it will crash in C++ DLL at this point, when actually calling the delegate

```
(*handler)(u_req, u_res);
```

So in the sample I provided, if I send request to `/THLinkAPI/PushEvent` it  works fine, but if I send it to `THLinkAPI/ConnectionChanged` it crashes.

Comment: What is `UServerUtils.NativeRequestToRequest` ? do you store RequestNative/ResponseNative ? They are not valid after native handler finished(because `safe_delete`) ... why don't you use IntPtr instead delegate directly ?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when unity has its own

Comment: @Selvin I have Request and RequestNative, RequestNative is a struct that has IntPtrs, and then I just parse these into regular values, for example, body, headers etc cause in the end, in Unity I don't want to deal with IntPtrs and such. Can't use directly, as I need to preporcess the request / response data.

Comment: @BugFinder How so? I've been looking for such a solution, even tried using external C# ones, like EmbedIO or Grapevine, however when it comes to SSL and HTTPS protocol, both just don't work in Unity - and only in Unity, they work perfectly in regular .NET Console App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that after getting some rest new ideas came to my mind and I've figured it out.

The issue was that I was passing a delegate from C# that was then referenced from C++ as a pointer, but no reference to it remained in C# which is why it got cleaned up by GC and when later I tried to deref and call the function from C++ it pointed to garbage memory. I solved the issue by modifying the code to save the delegates to a list:

```cs
        private List<ServerRequestHandlerNative> _reqHandlers = new List<ServerRequestHandlerNative>();

        public void Post(string route, ServerRequestHandler handler)
        {
            ServerRequestHandlerNative nativeHandler = delegate (IntPtr reqPtr, IntPtr resPtr)
            {
                // Save the handler
                ServerRequestHandler localHandler = handler;

                RequestNative reqNat = Marshal.PtrToStructure<RequestNative>(reqPtr);
                ResponseNative resNat = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ResponseNative>(resPtr);

                Request req = UServerUtils.NativeRequestToRequest(reqNat);
                Response res = UServerUtils.NativeResponseToResponse(resNat);

                Console.WriteLine("[C#] GET Successfully marshaled data. Now calling handler.");

                localHandler(req, res);
            };

            // Save the handler to keep the ref count
            _reqHandlers.Add(nativeHandler);

            UServer_Post(m_ServerPtr, route, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(nativeHandler));
        }
```